# REST-Endpoint: Async execution without return value

Tags: asynchronous, jax-rs, quarkus

My problem might be very easy to solve, but I don't get it at the moment. In my Quarkus-App I have a REST-Endpoint which should call a method, don't wait for the result and immediately return a 202-HTTP-Statuscode.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response calculateAsync(String input) {
    process();
    return Response.accepted().build();
}
```

I've read the Quarkus-Documentation about Vert.x and asynchronous processing. But the point there is: the processing is done asynchronously, but the client waits for the result. My clients don't need to wait, because there is no return value. It's something like the invocation of a batch-processing.

So I need something like a `new Thread`, but with all the Quarkus-Context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've found a solution:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response calculateAsync(String input) {
    Uni.createFrom().item(input).emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool()).subscribe().with(
            item -> process(input), Throwable::printStackTrace
    );

    return Response.accepted().build();
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness: There are some problems with `@RequestScope` when using this async approach: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13013

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Suspended AsyncResponse response` in parameters and make the method return `void`
Here's example of a similar method:

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void hello(@Suspended AsyncResponse response) throws InterruptedException {
        response.resume(Response.ok().build());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Do some work");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a comment at @Kavithakaran 's answer. It works, but I'm having problem with the context.